# Predicting the class of images using parameters of trained ConvNet

Tags: python, classification, theano, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use Convolutional Neural Networks for classification of images. I have gone through this [tutorial](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) on Deep Learning and implemented the given [code](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network3.py) with many modifications. I added more layers of convolution and max-pooling and altered the inputs for accepting an input of 166x166. To save the parameters after training, we used cPickle.dump() in the function save() which is defined for each layer (ConvPool, FullyConnected and Softmax) separately.  This function is called after the training is completed, in sgd() method, for all layers. In another program, the parameters for the softmax, fully connected layer and convolution layers are loaded back from the .p pickled files in another program which is the same, except we are not calling the SGD method. The problem is that, I want to print y_out of the Softmax layer (y_out is used to calculate the accuracy of our network), to obtain a prediction of the class of the image. But after trying

```
#print net.layers[-1].y_out.eval()
#x2 = net.layers[-1].y_out
#y2 = T.cast(x2, 'int32')
#print (pp(net.layers[-1].y_out))
#help(T.argmax)

#print net.layers[-1].y_out.shape.eval()
```

I am still getting 'argmax' as the value of Tensor Variable,' y_out or otherwise an error of Missing Input Error when I used the eval() function to get the value of the Tensor Variable.

Thus need help to print the prediction for a single test image.

This is the code for network3.py (renamed as net3.py) after our modification:

```
"""net3.py
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

A Theano-based program for training and running simple neural
networks.

Supports several layer types (fully connected, convolutional, max
pooling, softmax), and activation functions (sigmoid, tanh, and
rectified linear units, with more easily added).

When run on a CPU, this program is much faster than network.py and
network2.py.  However, unlike network.py and network2.py it can also
be run on a GPU, which makes it faster still.

Because the code is based on Theano, the code is different in many
ways from network.py and network2.py.  However, where possible I have
tried to maintain consistency with the earlier programs.  In
particular, the API is similar to network2.py.  Note that I have
focused on making the code simple, easily readable, and easily
modifiable.  It is not optimized, and omits many desirable features.

This program incorporates ideas from the Theano documentation on
convolutional neural nets (notably,
http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html ), from Misha Denil's
implementation of dropout (https://github.com/mdenil/dropout ), and
from Chris Olah (http://colah.github.io ).

"""
#tts refers to trying to save

#### Libraries
# Standard library
import json
import cPickle
import gzip
import load
# Third-party libraries
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from theano.tensor.nnet import conv
from theano.tensor.nnet import softmax
from theano.tensor import shared_randomstreams
from theano.tensor.signal import downsample
from theano import pp

# Activation functions for neurons
def linear(z): return z
def ReLU(z): return T.maximum(0.0, z)
from theano.tensor.nnet import sigmoid
from theano.tensor import tanh

'''
#### Constants
GPU = True
if GPU:
    try: theano.config.device = 'gpu'
    except: pass # it's already set
    print "Trying to run under a GPU.  If this is not desired, then modify "+\
        "network3.py\nto set the GPU flag to False."

    theano.config.floatX = 'float32'
else:
    print "Running with a CPU.  If this is not desired, then the modify "+\
        "network3.py to set\nthe GPU flag to True."
'''
print "DEVICE IS:" ,theano.config.device
#### Load the MNIST data
def load_data_shared(filename="../data/mnist.pkl.gz"):
    f = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    def shared(data):
        """Place the data into shared variables.  This allows Theano to copy
        the data to the GPU, if one is available.

        """
        shared_x = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(data[0], dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=True)
        shared_y = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(data[1], dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=True)
        return shared_x, T.cast(shared_y, "int32")
    return [shared(training_data), shared(validation_data), shared(test_data)]

def load_mydata_shared():
    test_data = load.load_data()

    def shared(data):
        """Place the data into shared variables.  This allows Theano to copy
        the data to the GPU, if one is available.

        """
        print "data:",data
        shared_x = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(data[0], dtype=theano.config.floatX))
        shared_y = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(data[1], dtype=theano.config.floatX))
        return shared_x, T.cast(shared_y, "int32")
    return [shared(test_data)]

#### Main class used to construct and train networks
class Network(object):


    def __init__(self, layers, mini_batch_size):
        """Takes a list of `layers`, describing the network architecture, and
        a value for the `mini_batch_size` to be used during training
        by stochastic gradient descent.

        """
        self.layers = layers
        self.mini_batch_size = mini_batch_size
        self.params = [param for layer in self.layers for param in layer.params]
        self.x = T.matrix("x")
        self.y = T.ivector("y")
       # self.x1 = T.matrix('x')
       # self.y1 = T.ivector('y')
       # self.x2 = T.matrix('x')
       # self.y2 = T.ivector('y')
        init_layer = self.layers[0]


        init_layer.set_inpt(self.x, self.x, self.mini_batch_size)
        for j in xrange(1, len(self.layers)):
            prev_layer, layer  = self.layers[j-1], self.layers[j]
            layer.set_inpt(
                prev_layer.output, prev_layer.output_dropout, self.mini_batch_size)
        self.output = self.layers[-1].output
        self.output_dropout = self.layers[-1].output_dropout
        print "class issss:",pp(T.cast(self.layers[-1].y_out.shape,'int32'))

    def SGD(self, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta,
           test_data, lmbda=0.0):

        """Train the network using mini-batch stochastic gradient descent."""

        test_x, test_y = test_data




        print "tex:",test_x
        print "tey:",test_y
        # compute number of minibatches for training, validation and testing
        print "Epochs:"+str(epochs)
        print "Mini-batch size:"+str(mini_batch_size)
        print "Eta:"+str(eta)

        num_test_batches = size(test_data)/mini_batch_size

        # define the (regularized) cost function, symbolic gradients, and updates
        l2_norm_squared = sum([(layer.w**2).sum() for layer in self.layers])


        # define functions to train a mini-batch, and to compute the
        # accuracy in validation and test mini-batches.
        i = T.lscalar() # mini-batch index

        test_mb_accuracy = theano.function(
            [i], self.layers[-1].accuracy(self.y),
            givens={
                self.x:
                test_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size],
                self.y:
                test_y[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
            })
        self.test_mb_predictions = theano.function(
            [i], self.layers[-1].y_out,
            givens={
                self.x:
                test_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
            })


        test_accuracy = np.mean([test_mb_accuracy(j) for j in xrange(num_test_batches)])
        print('The corresponding test accuracy is {0:.2%}'.format(test_accuracy))






        print("Finished training network.")
        print("Best validation accuracy of {0:.2%} obtained at iteration {1}".format(
            best_validation_accuracy, best_iteration))
        print("Corresponding test accuracy of {0:.2%}".format(test_accuracy))

#### Define layer types

class ConvPoolLayer(object):
    """Used to create a combination of a convolutional and a max-pooling
    layer.  A more sophisticated implementation would separate the
    two, but for our purposes we'll always use them together, and it
    simplifies the code, so it makes sense to combine them.

    """

    def __init__(self, filter_shape, image_shape, poolsize=(2, 2),
                 activation_fn=ReLU):
        """`filter_shape` is a tuple of length 4, whose entries are the number
        of filters, the number of input feature maps, the filter height, and the
        filter width.

        `image_shape` is a tuple of length 4, whose entries are the
        mini-batch size, the number of input feature maps, the image
        height, and the image width.

        `poolsize` is a tuple of length 2, whose entries are the y and
        x pooling sizes.

        """
        self.filter_shape = filter_shape
        self.image_shape = image_shape
        self.poolsize = poolsize
        self.activation_fn=activation_fn
        # initialize weights and biases
        n_out = (filter_shape[0]*np.prod(filter_shape[2:])/np.prod(poolsize))
        self.w = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(
                np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=np.sqrt(1.0/n_out), size=filter_shape),
                dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            borrow=True)
        self.b = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(
                np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1.0, size=(filter_shape[0],)),
                dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            borrow=True)
        self.load()
        self.params = [self.w, self.b]


    def set_inpt(self, inpt, inpt_dropout, mini_batch_size):
        self.inpt = inpt.reshape(self.image_shape)
        conv_out = conv.conv2d(
            input=self.inpt, filters=self.w, filter_shape=self.filter_shape,
            image_shape=self.image_shape)
        pooled_out = downsample.max_pool_2d(
            input=conv_out, ds=self.poolsize, ignore_border=True)
        self.output = self.activation_fn(
            pooled_out + self.b.dimshuffle('x', 0, 'x', 'x'))
        self.output_dropout = self.output # no dropout in the convolutional layers
    def load(self):
        """Save the neural network to the file ``filename``."""     
        save_file=open('/home/sweta/BE_PROJECT/tryingtosave/cl.p')
        self.w.set_value(cPickle.load(save_file),borrow=True)
        self.b.set_value(cPickle.load(save_file),borrow=True)

class FullyConnectedLayer(object):

    def __init__(self, n_in, n_out, activation_fn=ReLU, p_dropout=0.5):
        self.n_in = n_in
        self.n_out = n_out
        self.activation_fn = activation_fn
        self.p_dropout = p_dropout
        # Initialize weights and biases
        self.w = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(
                np.random.normal(
                    loc=0.0, scale=np.sqrt(1.0/n_out), size=(n_in, n_out)),
                dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            name='w', borrow=True)
        self.b = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(n_out,)),
                       dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            name='b', borrow=True)
        self.load()
        self.params = [self.w, self.b]


    def set_inpt(self, inpt, inpt_dropout, mini_batch_size):
        self.inpt = inpt.reshape((mini_batch_size, self.n_in))
        self.output = self.activation_fn(
            (1-self.p_dropout)*T.dot(self.inpt, self.w) + self.b)
        self.y_out = T.argmax(self.output, axis=1)
        self.inpt_dropout = dropout_layer(
            inpt_dropout.reshape((mini_batch_size, self.n_in)), self.p_dropout)
        self.output_dropout = self.activation_fn(
            T.dot(self.inpt_dropout, self.w) + self.b)

    def accuracy(self, y):
        "Return the accuracy for the mini-batch."
        return T.mean(T.eq(y, self.y_out))

    def load(self):
        """Save the neural network to the file ``filename``."""     
        save_file=open('/home/sweta/BE_PROJECT/tryingtosave/fcl.p')
        self.w.set_value(cPickle.load(save_file),borrow=True)
        self.b.set_value(cPickle.load(save_file),borrow=True)

class SoftmaxLayer(object):

    def __init__(self, n_in, n_out, p_dropout=0.5):
        self.n_in = n_in
        self.n_out = n_out
        self.p_dropout = p_dropout
        # Initialize weights and biases
        self.w = theano.shared(
            np.zeros((n_in, n_out), dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            name='w', borrow=True)
        self.b = theano.shared(
            np.zeros((n_out,), dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            name='b', borrow=True)
        self.load()
        self.params = [self.w, self.b]


    def set_inpt(self, inpt, inpt_dropout, mini_batch_size):
        self.inpt = inpt.reshape((mini_batch_size, self.n_in))
        self.output = softmax((1-self.p_dropout)*T.dot(self.inpt, self.w) + self.b)
        self.y_out = T.argmax(self.output, axis=1)
        self.inpt_dropout = dropout_layer(
            inpt_dropout.reshape((mini_batch_size, self.n_in)), self.p_dropout)
        self.output_dropout = softmax(T.dot(self.inpt_dropout, self.w) + self.b)

    def cost(self, net):
        "Return the log-likelihood cost."
        return -T.mean(T.log(self.output_dropout)[T.arange(net.y.shape[0]), net.y])

    def accuracy(self, y):
        "Return the accuracy for the mini-batch."
        print "class is:", self.y_out
        return T.mean(T.eq(y, self.y_out))

    def load(self):
        """Save the neural network to the file ``filename``."""     
        save_file=open('/home/sweta/BE_PROJECT/tryingtosave/sml.p')
        self.w.set_value(cPickle.load(save_file),borrow=True)
        self.b.set_value(cPickle.load(save_file),borrow=True)
#### Miscellanea
def size(data):
    "Return the size of the dataset `data`."
    return data[0].get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]

def dropout_layer(layer, p_dropout):
    srng = shared_randomstreams.RandomStreams(
        np.random.RandomState(0).randint(999999))
    mask = srng.binomial(n=1, p=1-p_dropout, size=layer.shape)
    return layer*T.cast(mask, theano.config.floatX)
```

The main code is:

```
import net3
import load
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import pp
from net3 import Network
from net3 import ConvPoolLayer, FullyConnectedLayer, SoftmaxLayer

test_data = net3.load_mydata_shared()



mini_batch_size = 10
net = Network([ ConvPoolLayer(image_shape=(mini_batch_size, 1, 166, 166),filter_shape=(5, 1, 5,5), poolsize=(2, 2)),
                 ConvPoolLayer(image_shape=(mini_batch_size, 5, 81, 81),filter_shape=(10, 5, 6,6), poolsize=(2, 2)),
         ConvPoolLayer(image_shape=(mini_batch_size, 10, 38, 38),filter_shape=(15, 10, 5, 5 ),poolsize=(2, 2)),
        ConvPoolLayer(image_shape=(mini_batch_size, 15, 17, 17),filter_shape=(20, 15, 4, 4 ),poolsize=(2, 2)),
        ConvPoolLayer(image_shape=(mini_batch_size, 20, 7, 7),filter_shape=(40, 20, 2, 2 ),poolsize=(2, 2)),
        FullyConnectedLayer(n_in=40*3*3, n_out=100),SoftmaxLayer(n_in=100, n_out=3)], mini_batch_size)
#print net.layers[-1].y_out.eval()
#x2 = net.layers[-1].y_out
#y2 = T.cast(x2, 'int32')
#print (pp(net.layers[-1].y_out))
#help(T.argmax)

#print net.layers[-1].y_out.shape.eval()


#net.SGD( 2, mini_batch_size, 0.03 ,test_data)
```

The code to load the single test image in .mat form is as follows:

```
"""
mnist_loader
~~~~~~~~~~~~

A library to load the MNIST image data.  For details of the data
structures that are returned, see the doc strings for ``load_data``
and ``load_data_wrapper``.  In practice, ``load_data_wrapper`` is the
function usually called by our neural network code.
"""

#### Libraries
# Standard library
import cPickle
import gzip

# Third-party libraries
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
from random import shuffle

def load_data():
    matx = sio.loadmat('exact_one_x.mat')
    datax = matx['X']

        datax=datax.transpose()
    print datax.shape
    maty = sio.loadmat('one_y.mat')
    datay = maty['M']
    datay=datay.transpose()

    print datay.shape


    test_data = (datax,datay[0])

    return ( test_data)

def load_data_wrapper():
    """Return a tuple containing ``(training_data, validation_data,
    test_data)``. Based on ``load_data``, but the format is more
    convenient for use in our implementation of neural networks.

    In particular, ``training_data`` is a list containing 50,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  ``x`` is a 784-dimensional numpy.ndarray
    containing the input image.  ``y`` is a 10-dimensional
    numpy.ndarray representing the unit vector corresponding to the
    correct digit for ``x``.

    ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are lists containing 10,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  In each case, ``x`` is a 784-dimensional
    numpy.ndarry containing the input image, and ``y`` is the
    corresponding classification, i.e., the digit values (integers)
    corresponding to ``x``.

    Obviously, this means we're using slightly different formats for
    the training data and the validation / test data.  These formats
    turn out to be the most convenient for use in our neural network
    code."""
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (27556, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = zip(training_inputs, training_results)
    shuffle(training_data)
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (27556, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1])
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (27556, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = zip(test_inputs, te_d[1])
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def vectorized_result(j):
    """Return a 10-dimensional unit vector with a 1.0 in the jth
    position and zeroes elsewhere.  This is used to convert a digit
    (0...9) into a corresponding desired output from the neural
    network."""
    e = np.zeros((3, 1))
    e[j] = 1.0
    return e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the test_mb_predictions function which is already defined in your code . You just need to load a single image, in your testing code, with a batch-size of 1, (and not 10) and print the class as returned by test_mb_predictions.